# Laravel - CSRF token not working with ajax call resulting in 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

## The problem

I have a simple search field which is a form. When it is submitted, the following code is responsible to get the result. The code gives me an Internal Server Error. This causes me not to enter my PHP search function in the controller. I'm thinking it has something to do with my tokens setup. They work with other ajax calls though coded by someone else.

Note: this code used to print the search query results in my console. Due to a change (by implementing the token script in master blade) it stopped doing that. So my workflow is stuck at posting the ajax call. Can you find whats causing this error to reappear or appear at all? Thanks in advance.

## The code

#### Script

```
$("#searchonfrontpage").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var whattosearch = $("#searchFRONT").val();
console.log("searching... " + whattosearch + ".");

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/", 
    data: { whattosearch: whattosearch }, 
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

#### Routes

```
//just in case
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') :     Input::get('_token');
 if (Session::token() != $token)
    throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
});

//frontpage routes
Route::get('/','frontpageController@frontpage');
Route::post('/', 'frontpageController@search');
```

#### Tokens script in master blade (works with other ajax calls)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

#### The search function

```
public function search() {

    //not making it here because of the 500 server error with post
    print_r("call made");

    $q = $_POST["whattosearch"];
    print_r($q);

    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
    $query = DB::table('projects');

    foreach($searchTerms as $term){
        $query->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'projects.user_id')
              ->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
              ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
              ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
              ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%')
              ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    $projects = $query->get();

    print_r($projects); //used to be able to see these results, but not anymore

    //return data view here (also gives a 500 error when I used to be able to get projects)

    //return View::make( 'viewfile' )->with( 'data', $projects );
    //return View::make('projects', compact('projects'));
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel logs and/or the HTPP server logs to see what's the error?

Comment: Thanks for writing a clear question! Couple things to try: 1) Try changing `X-CSRF-Token` to `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the off chance it is case sensitive (I can't remember). 2) Try passing your token as `_token` in the object passed as data in your AJAX call. 3) Make sure the AJAX pre-filter is wrapped with a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so the token is set after the element is available.

Comment: can you please comment of foreach loop code in search() method, and then call Ajax. I hope you will get something new output.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! 
Jay: Since my call wont make it into the function, I'm not getting output.
Jeremy: I have tried your methods. Didn't seem to fix it for me, sorry. I'm a bit confused on how to do the second one. I have been able to get the token into a string, I can add it to my data attribute. Not sure what do do with it. 
Bogdan: Haven't checked on the server itself, will do!

Comment: I have started anew with this tutorial: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoGITOPpBfU). The code hasn't changed much, so wont influence the following:
The tutorial allows me to do ajax requests, but my code crashes at the $projects = $query->get(); now, resulting in an unsuccessful call. The new error I am receiving is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` while again getting a 500 error. This error links to my file VM14763. As if something gets printed in that document. I see a **(** before <!DOCTYPE html>. But not a single thing is printed / vardumped.

Comment: This sounds like a new problem. It's probably best to answer this question with what you changed to fix your AJAX call to work and open a new question on stackoverflow for the other problem. Also, you should really try to debug your code with phpstorm/xdebug in order to see where things are failing and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a result by following this [tutorial] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoGITOPpBfU). Not sure what the initial problem was.